# RestKit not mapping objects

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm trying to access an object in JSON, but RestKit keeps telling me that paths do not match, but actually they match!
This is driving me nuts. I have tried changing path pattern to `catalog/item?category_id=:id` but it didn't help.

```
<RKResponseDescriptor: 0x7c6aba0 baseURL=http://pornhub.com/freeapi/public/bit/ pathPattern=catalog/item?category_id=1 statusCodes=200-299> failed to match: response path 'catalog/item?category_id=1' did not match the path pattern 'catalog/item?category_id=1'.
```

Here is the code:

```
[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:goodMapping
                                            pathPattern:@"catalog/item?category_id=1"
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:statusCodes]]];
```

The only minor difference is that I am getting the item in array and not raw item itself as in other mappings. Maybe this plays some role, but I am not sure.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: How are you calling to get the response data? You may need to use dynamic mappings for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was not matching urls in request and mapping. After I copy and paste them to be the same everything worked.